# Parse partition paths when partitioning="hive" without providing a schema?

Tags: pyarrow

I parse lists of paths (sent through Airflow XComs, so it needs to be a list of strings), in order to create a filter expression.

```
file = "container/path/to/date_id=20220103/test=2/test.parquet"
ds.partitioning(schema=pa.schema([("date_id", pa.int32()), ("test", pa.int8())]), flavor="hive").parse(file)

<pyarrow.compute.Expression (date_id == 20220103)>
```

That works fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to just use the "hive" shortcut instead of specifying the schema.

```
ds.partitioning(flavor="hive").parse(file)

AttributeError: 'pyarrow._dataset.PartitioningFactory' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

I can't seem to figure out how the partitions are discovered when using "hive" without a schema. I do not really care about the data type for each partition column - ultimately I am just creating a consolidated filter based on a list of Parquet fragment paths.